# Unable to access values from object

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the date and time from this object:
`Recurr\RecurrenceCollection Object ( [elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array ( [0] => Recurr\Recurrence Object ( [start:protected] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-01-24 01:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [end:protected] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-01-24 01:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [index:protected] => 1 ) ) )`

I have reached to dateTime object using:

```
foreach($events as $event){
            $event=(array)$event;
            foreach($event as $key=>$value){
                echo $key.'<br>';
                //echo date_format(new DateTime($value),'F d,Y');
                //echo $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }
            print_r($event);
        }
```

But now if I try to use: `echo $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
It says: `Call to a member function format() on integer`

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have read almost 100 posts here on Stack Overflow but nothing has helped. Please if someone can help me out with this.

What I need is: Date and Time from that DateTime Object.

Comment: `echo (new \DateTime($value))->format('F d,Y');`

Comment: @Dharman I did use this also, it says: `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: var_dump($value) so you know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need cast `$event` to `array`. Try this:

```
foreach($events as $event){
    $start = $event->getStart();
    echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! It worked like a magic. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

The fields are protected, so they can't be accessed like that. you should add getters in the class liek `public function getDate(){ return $this->date }` and now you can access it by `$object->getDate()` or change the access modifier to public of that date attribute.